# Remove Separator Line between Footer and Header IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a tableView in which i want first cells footer and Second cell header to be merged. I tried to remove both but there is a separator line remain in between.

Is there a way i can remove the separator between footer of first cell and header of second cell.

One more thing I was trying to give the height to the footer and header 
in

```
- (UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView* footerView = nil;

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)];
           // footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;

        case 1:
        {
            footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
        }
            break;

        case 2:
        {
            footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return footerView;
}
```

But still for both header and footer height remains same
I am unable to know why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do default way to hide the separator for a particular cell, because line separator is a property of **UITableView**. However you can use custom cell with bottom line image (Which is present at bottom of custom cell's container view) and you can easily hide and show that image like below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Your_custom_cell *cell = //initialise your cell
    if (indexPath.row == 0){
    cell.bottom_line_image.hidden = YES;
    }
    else
    {
    cell.bottom_line_image.hidden =NO;
    }
```

Don't forgot to set separator style of tableview in *viewdidload()*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    your_table_istance.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
}
```

Comment: You need to implement below tableview delegate method to return footer height   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGFloat footerHieght = 30.0;
    
    if (section == 0)
    {
        footerHieght = 1.0;
    }
    return footerHieght;
    
}